# Add country flags

Tags: plugins

I am working on a personal plugin where I display information about Football clubs. I fetch most data from a private API and each club comes with a `countryCode` - the country ISO code (like CN for China).

I would like to use the code inside a `class` and display the flag instead. Like this

[image]

Any suggestions on what's the best solution to achieve this? I was thinking on adding all the flags to my `uploads` folder and load them from there, but taking into consideration there are 200+ country flags I'll need I am not so sure anymore.

An alternative would be to look for public APIs that provide the image, but then again, I am dependent on 3rd parties API that might shut down anytime.

Any ideas are welcome! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to import data from 3rd party API into your database. By this you do not need to rely on any API.

Your page performance will also be increased as it will reduce external request.

So you need to do one time job to fetch all the data from API, stores it into your database. For flag image, if API is providing you image, then it must be in base64 which you can directly store in your Database table.